# Command line tool to format tables

Tags: perl, bash, awk

I am a a big fan of one-liners using `sed` `awk` `perl` and other tools. But there are things hard to do in one-liner like when you working with a CSV file and there are comma between quotes, or when you want to print a centralized field with `printf`.

Few months ago I wrote `ftable` more for fun than anything else, but last weekend I took it seriously, created a github repository and a tutorial for it.

`ftable` tutorial: https://github.com/tlopo/ftable/blob/master/README.md

`ftable` code: https://github.com/tlopo/ftable/blob/master/ftable.pl

Do you know of a tool that's similar to `ftable`? I hate feeling like re-inventing the wheel :-)

Comment: It is good that you want to share your code, but this is not the best suited place. Try to ask something more specific. Also, you'd better get hints in Code Review.

Comment: The question is about the tools you know that are similar. If there is anybody willing to review the code will be bonus :)

Comment: There's a specific site for code reviews (http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Polling questions are not welcome here, see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The first question is appropriate for SO, though. Removing the part that's not.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for mentioning codereview, I was not aware of that.

Comment: @ikegami: there's a specific close reason for that sort of question. And specific guidance in the [help/on-topic] for that.

Comment: @Mat, Of course. That's why I removed it. It would be stupid to close the whole question because half of it was inappropriate for SO.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm talking about the part you left, i.e. tool recommendation.

Comment: I believe the question is still valid (after @ikegami edited it) as per help center: software tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: @Mat, He's not asking for a tool recommendation (which would require an opinion as to the relative ranking of the available tools); he's aksing if a tool exists (which isn't opinion-based). I realize the difference is subtle, but it doesn't have the problems tool recommendations have.

Comment: Now that I think about it, there's also a site for that: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (strict guidelines for questions though). @ikegami: same problem, different wording. The reason questions that ask for locating software aren't well received is the amount of spam and low-quality answers in general they generate. (Maybe Tiago's script is the one-and-only thing, or maybe there's just one other tool like it, but that's not really the point.) Anyway, I'm not the Dictator here, if no-one else votes to close, fine with me :-)

Comment: There are a few problems with your code, but what makes it most unreadable for me are the overly short and incomprehensible identifiers that you use. No one could guess what any of these mean `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$i`, `$l`, `$m`, `$n`, `$s`, `$x`, `$z`, `%h`, `@a`, `@b`, `@d`, `@l`. Even `$i`,. which is normally used for an array index, or at least an arbitrary integer, is reserved for a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know and have used Python's [prettytable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/), it's complete and simple to use. Your command could use this library (or similar) to do the "drawing" part (to respond to your 'Am I re-inventing the wheel' question).